# What is error 324? Is it related to Google Chrome? Or Verizon Webmail?

Tags: browser, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, webmail

My in-laws are having trouble with signing into their Verizon Webmail account at webmail.verizon.net, only when they are on their wireless network.

When they try to log in from wireless they get "Error 324" in the browser, in both Google Chrome ***and*** Internet Explorer 8.

But they can access any other site, and they can get on their Verizon email when they plug in directly to the browser.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

Error 324 in Chrome is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I would packet capture and see if the response is empty, or whether the connection is being closed.

It may be a case that their router is choking on the response returned, returning the HTTP headers but not the body of the response.

There is [an open bug for ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=21675) in Chrome, but it appears the symptom is the issue happens in Chrome *and* another browser (in this case IE8).

Answer (score 0):

This error could be for two reasons. First, you need to clear the browser cache and second one need to remove or disable the Internet secuirty if any. Also, run [WinsockFix](http://www.brothersoft.com/winsockfix-66663.html).

Answer (score 0):

There’s several things to try:

- Try rebooting the computer
- Try rebooting the router
- Check the connection plugs for loose connections
- Try a wired connection to see if it is only the wireless
- If you can use Internet Explorer, use it to test if you get the same error
- Optimise the browser
- Check if the LAN is enabled or connected in Control Panel